# Entity Framework asks to update-database when migration is already appended

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

ASP.NET WebAPI app published on Azure, Entity Framework code first.

After publishing with migrations executing on application start (first pic) I can't add new migration and work with database context ("model backing the 'DatabaseContext' context has changed since the database was created" exception). On adding new migration EF breaks with error:

> Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [migration name]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.

Looks like EF doens't see migrations from __MigrationHistory table. I checked this table and last migrations exists.

In web.config there are only one connection string.

If it's important, DatabaseContextWithoutCache inherit DatabaseContext (they have different DbConfigurationType).

After adding null initializer `Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);` to database context it works but I still can't add any migration.

Why does Entity Framework doesn't see that migration is already appended to database? `update-database` breaks because there are already tables and columns in db.

**EDIT:**

In my migration list 2 migrations. I rolled back to init (first) migration and remove second. Then add-migration (now it contains changes from second and new changes) and run `update-database`. It works.

But EF ignore that db is up-to-date and breaks with "model backing the 'DatabaseContext' context has changed since the database was created" exception.

OMG I DON'T UNDERSTAND

[image: first pic]

Comment: If you don't care about the past migrations, tear everything down (remove table __MigrationHistory and migrations from code. Now enable-migrations, then create a new baseline: add-migration -BaselineName -IgnoreChanges followed by update-database.

Comment: @SteveGreene I did it. And first 2 migrations were ok but 3rd braked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently under VS 2013. If in the Package Manager Console you run the command `add-migration {name}` (optionally adding `-startupprojectname {MyProjectName}`) the EF should generate a new migration file for you. If that migration file has *any* content, then it believes you are not where you should be and you should then run `update-database` with that new migration in place.

Unfortunately it does seem possible to get caught in a loop with this (it happened to me) and there are quite a few SO Q&As which concern this. Very best of luck solving it.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, there is a migration pending against the database.

Use the following command from the package manager (replace values with your own)

```
update-database -projectname yourprojectname -connectionstring "yourconnectionstring"
```

Then, create your new migration....

```
add-migration yournewmigrationname -projectname yourprojectname -connectionstring "yourconnectionstring"
```

And finally, run the newly created migration

```
update-database -projectname yourprojectname -connectionstring "yourconnectionstring"
```